# split the string into two arrays

Tags: powershell

I have a string like below

```
abc-ijk-90-hortons-899-mnb-8037-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KEW-197.127.255.0/23
abc-ijk-90-hortons-975-mnb-8024-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KUYW-198.157.150.0/23
abc-ijk-90-hortons-356-mnb-8022-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-JHT-199.127.132.0/23
```

I want to split the string into

```
c1= {8037,8024,8022}
c2= {POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KEW-197.127.255.0/23,POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KUYW-198.157.150.0/23,POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-JHT-199.127.132.0/23}
```

c3 should display as below

```
Number  Name
8037    POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KEW-197.127.255.0/23
8024    POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KUYW-198.157.150.0/23
8022    POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-JHT-199.127.132.0/23
```

Comment: [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Comment: Probably better to split into **one** array of _objects_. Matching multiple arrays together by index is an anti-pattern and poor practice. Plus, if you do this, you get `c3` automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- splitting the lines of the string at the `-` but limiting the split to 8 times,
  thus keeping the `POI-...` up to the end of the line in one piece
- then selecting zero based index [6,7] to stuff into vars $Number,$Name
- Building a [PSCustomObject] of these two variables.
- finally building $c1,$c2 from the properties of $c3

---

```
$string = @"
abc-ijk-90-hortons-899-mnb-8037-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KEW-197.127.255.0/23
abc-ijk-90-hortons-975-mnb-8024-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KUYW-198.157.150.0/23
abc-ijk-90-hortons-356-mnb-8022-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-JHT-199.127.132.0/23
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$c3 = foreach ($line in $string){
    $Number,$Name= ($line -split '-',8)[6,7]
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Number = $Number
        Name   = $Name
    }
}
# it's not quite clear what type you expect $c1,$c2 to be.
# a simple joined string
$c1 = '{'+($c3.Number -join ',')+'}'
$c2 = '{'+($c3.Name   -join ',')+'}'

$c1;$c2;$c3
```

Sample output:

```
{8037,8024,8022}
{POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KEW-197.127.255.0/23,POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KUYW-198.157.150.0/23,POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-JHT-199.127.132.0/23}

Number Name
------ ----
8037   POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KEW-197.127.255.0/23
8024   POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KUYW-198.157.150.0/23
8022   POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-JHT-199.127.132.0/23
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$Yourstring=@"
abc-ijk-90-hortons-899-mnb-8037-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KEW-197.127.255.0/23
abc-ijk-90-hortons-975-mnb-8024-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KUYW-198.157.150.0/23
abc-ijk-90-hortons-356-mnb-8022-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-JHT-199.127.132.0/23
"@

$C3=@()

$Yourstring -split "`n" | %{

$marray=$_ -split '-'
$C3+=[pscustomobject]@{Number=$marray[6];Name=$marray[7..($marray.Count-1)] -join '-'}

}

$C1=$C3.Number
$C2=$C3.Name
```

Comment: Its getting error:-Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 
'op_Addition'.
At C:\k2d\test9.ps1:12 char:1
+ $C3+=[pscustomobject]@{Number=$marray[6];Name=$marray[7..($marray.Count-1)] -joi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Sorry, i have initilized $C1 and not $C3, it's corrected

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the number you want will always be in the same position you can try something like this:

```
$string = 'abc-ijk-90-hortons-899-mnb-8037-POI-AS-QWE-ZXC-TYUIOP-KEW-197.127.255.0/23'

# Split on dash
$array = $string.Split('-')

# build new array from position 7 on
$name = @()
for($i = 7; $i -lt $array.count; $i++){
    $name += $array[$i]
}

# create PS object with the Number from position 6 and the remainder rejoined together.
[pscustomobject]@{Number = $array[6]; Name = $name -join('-')}
```